# Network library based on boost::asio

Tags: c++, io, boost, tcp

I'm currently trying to develop an easy to use TCP networking library based on `boost::asio`.
This is my first attempt to work with `boost::asio` and therefore I've got some questions:

1. Firstly, is my code okay and easy to understand?
2. Are there any misleading conventions?
3. Are there any memory leaks?
4. Is there any improvement for my written code?
5. What about the style-guide?

Additional information about the three different classes:

- `TCPSession` handles the read/write operations of the socket.
- `TCPClient` contains an object of the `TCPSession` and handles the connection to a server.
- `TCPServer` holds an acceptor and `std::unordererd_map<std::uint64_t, TCPSessionPtr>` with all the active connections.

Base.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL 1
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
#include <spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h>
#include <spdlog/async.h>
#include "Utils.hpp"



namespace nelw
{
    typedef std::uint64_t id_type;
    typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_t;
    typedef boost::asio::io_context& io_context_ref;
    typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor tcp_acceptor;

    class TCPSession;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<TCPSession> TConnectionPtr;

    typedef std::function<void(const TConnectionPtr&)> TConnectionCallback;
    typedef std::function<void(const TConnectionPtr&, const boost::system::error_code&)> TErrorCallback;
    
    class Buffer;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Buffer> TBufferPtr;
    typedef std::function<void(const TConnectionPtr&, const TBufferPtr&)> TRecvCallback;
}
```

Utils.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
namespace nelw
{
    template<class F, class...Args>
    void for_each_arg(F f, Args&&...args) {
        (f(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    }
}
```

TCPSession.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Buffer.hpp"

namespace nelw
{
    class TCPSession : public std::enable_shared_from_this<TCPSession>
    {
    public:
        TCPSession(io_context_ref context, std::uint64_t buffer_size = 4096);
        virtual ~TCPSession();
        friend class TCPServer;
        friend class TCPClient;
    public:
        auto socket() -> socket_t& { return socket_; }
        auto write_buffer() ->TBufferPtr& { return write_buffer_; }
        auto id() -> id_type { return id_; }
        auto set_id(id_type id) { id_ = id; }

        auto read_buffer() ->TBufferPtr& { return read_buffer_; }
        bool is_connected() { return is_connected_; }
        template <class T> void set_dc_cb(T&& cb) { dc_cb_ = cb; }
        template <class T> void set_connection_cb(T&& cb) { connection_cb_ = cb; }
        template <class T> void set_recv_cb(T&& cb) { recv_cb_ = cb; }
        template <class T> void set_error_cb(T&& cb) { error_cb_ = cb; }


    public:
        void Disconnect();
        void Send(void* pData, size_t length);
        void Read();

        template <typename... Args> void Send(Args&&... args)
        {
            //constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(Args);
            std::uint32_t size = 0; 
            for_each_arg([&size](auto& arg) { size += sizeof(arg); }, args...);

            if (size <= 0)
                return;


            size_t offset = 0;
            std::vector<std::byte> buffer{ size };
            for_each_arg([&buffer, &offset](auto& arg) 
                {
                    std::memcpy(&buffer[offset], &arg, sizeof(arg));
                    offset += sizeof(arg);
                }
            , args...);

            Send((void*)buffer.data(), buffer.size()); 
        }

        void WriteProcess();
        void RemoteDisconnect();
    protected:
        virtual void OnError(const boost::system::error_code& ec);
        virtual void OnConnection();
        virtual void OnRecv();
    protected:
        io_context_ref context_; 
        socket_t socket_;
        id_type id_;
        std::function<void()> dc_cb_;
        TBufferPtr write_buffer_; // write buffer
        TBufferPtr read_buffer_;
        bool is_connected_;
        bool is_writing_;
        TConnectionCallback connection_cb_; 
        TRecvCallback recv_cb_; 
        TErrorCallback error_cb_;
    };

}
```

TCPSession.cpp

```cpp
#include "nelw/Base.hpp"
#include "nelw/TcpSession.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace nelw
{

    TCPSession::TCPSession(io_context_ref context, std::uint64_t buffer_size) : context_(context), socket_(context),  
        id_ { 0 }, dc_cb_{ nullptr }, 
        is_connected_ { true }, connection_cb_ { nullptr }, 
        recv_cb_ { nullptr }, error_cb_ { nullptr }, 
        is_writing_{ false }
    {
        if (buffer_size)
        {
            read_buffer_ = std::make_unique<nelw::Buffer>(buffer_size);
            write_buffer_ = std::make_unique<nelw::Buffer>(buffer_size);
        }
    }

    TCPSession::~TCPSession()
    {
        if (read_buffer_)
            read_buffer_.reset();

        if (write_buffer_)
            write_buffer_.reset();

        if (dc_cb_)
        {
            dc_cb_();
            dc_cb_ = nullptr;
        }

        spdlog::info("Remove from session! {}", id_);
    }

    void TCPSession::Disconnect()
    {
        if (!is_connected_)
            return;

        auto self{ shared_from_this() };
        context_.post([self]() {
            if (!self->socket().is_open())
                return;

            self->is_connected_ = false;
            self->socket_.cancel();
            self->socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
            self->socket_.close();
            self->OnConnection();
            if (self->dc_cb_)
            {
                self->dc_cb_();
                self->dc_cb_ = nullptr;
            }
        });
    }

    void TCPSession::Read()
    {
        if (!is_connected_)
            return;

        assert(read_buffer_);

        if (!socket_.is_open())
            return;
        //spdlog::debug("Start reading from {}", e.address().to_string(), e.port());

        auto self{ shared_from_this() };
        auto write_able = read_buffer_->WritableBytes(); 
        if (write_able <= 0)
        {
            //spdlog::debug("Waiting for bytes...");

            try
            {
                socket_.async_wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read, [self = shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                    if (!ec)
                    {
                        auto s = self->socket_.available();
                        if (s > 0)
                            self->read_buffer_->EnsureWritableBytes(s);

                        spdlog::debug("Ensure bytes size: {}", s);

                        self->Read();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self->OnError(ec);

                        if (boost::asio::error::eof == ec || boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec)
                        {
                            spdlog::debug("Disconnect from async_wait!");
                            self->RemoteDisconnect();
                        }
                    }
                });
                
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;//spdlog::error("socket_.async_wait -> {}", e.what());
            }
        }
        else if (write_able > 0)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_->WriteBegin(), read_buffer_->WritableBytes()),
                [self = shared_from_this()](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
                {
                    if (!ec)
                    {
                        if (length)
                        {
                            self->read_buffer_->WriteBytes(length);
                            self->OnRecv();
                        }

                        self->Read();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        self->OnError(ec);

                        if (boost::asio::error::eof == ec || boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec)
                        {
                            spdlog::debug("Disconnect from read!");
                            self->RemoteDisconnect();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    void TCPSession::Send(void* pData, size_t length)
    {
        if (!is_connected_)
            return;

        write_buffer_->Append(pData, length);

        if (!is_writing_)
            WriteProcess();
    }

    void TCPSession::WriteProcess()
    {
        if (!is_connected_)
            return;

        auto length = write_buffer_->length();
        if (length <= 0)
            return;

        auto self{ shared_from_this() };

        boost::asio::async_write(
            socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(write_buffer_->data(), write_buffer_->length()),
            [self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bytes_transfered)
            {
                if (ec)
                {
                    self->OnError(ec);

                    if (boost::asio::error::eof == ec || boost::asio::error::connection_reset == ec)
                        self->RemoteDisconnect();

                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bytes_transfered)
                    {
                        self->write_buffer_->Skip(bytes_transfered);

                        if (self->write_buffer_->length() > 0)
                            self->WriteProcess();
                        else
                            self->is_writing_ = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        );

        is_writing_ = true;
    }
    
    void TCPSession::RemoteDisconnect()
    {
        if (is_connected_)
        {
            is_connected_ = false;

            OnConnection();
            if (dc_cb_)
            {
                dc_cb_();
                dc_cb_ = nullptr;
            }

        }
    }

    void TCPSession::OnError(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (error_cb_)
            error_cb_(shared_from_this(), ec); 
    }

    void TCPSession::OnConnection()
    {
        if (connection_cb_)
            connection_cb_(shared_from_this());
    }

    void TCPSession::OnRecv()
    {
        if (recv_cb_)
            recv_cb_(shared_from_this(), read_buffer_);
    }
}
```

TCPClient.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "TcpSession.hpp"
namespace nelw
{
    class TCPClient
    {
        public:
            enum flags : std::uint8_t
            {
                kTimerRunning = (1 << 1), // for the connection_timer_
                kReconnecting = (1 << 2)
            };
            TCPClient(io_context_ref context);
            ~TCPClient(); 
            virtual TConnectionPtr CreateSession();
            void Connect(const std::string& host, std::uint16_t port);
            void Disconnect();

        // getters and setters
        public:
            void set_connection_timeout(boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type connection_timeout);
            auto connection_timeout() -> boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type;
            TConnectionPtr& connection();
        // end of getters and setters

            void Send(void* pData, size_t length);  
            template <typename... Args> void Send(Args&&... args)
            {
                if (connection_ && connection_->is_connected())
                    connection_->Send(args...);
            }

            template <class T> void set_connection_cb(T&& cb) { connection_cb_ = cb; }
            template <class T> void set_recv_cb(T&& cb) { recv_cb_ = cb; }
            template <class T> void set_error_cb(T&& cb) { error_cb_ = cb; }
            void set_buffer_size(std::uint64_t buffer_size); 
            void set_reconnect(bool b);
            bool is_connected(); 

        protected:
            io_context_ref context_;
            TConnectionPtr connection_; 
            std::uint8_t flags_;
            boost::asio::deadline_timer connection_timer_; 
            boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type connection_timeout_; 
            TConnectionCallback connection_cb_; 
            TErrorCallback error_cb_; 
            TRecvCallback recv_cb_; 
            std::uint64_t buffer_size_;

    };
}
```

TCPClient.cpp

```cpp
#include "nelw/Base.hpp"
#include "nelw/TcpClient.hpp"
#include "nelw/TcpSession.hpp"

namespace nelw
{
    TCPClient::TCPClient(io_context_ref context) : context_{ context }, flags_{ 0 }, connection_timer_{ context }, connection_timeout_(boost::posix_time::seconds(5)),
                                                   connection_cb_{ nullptr }, error_cb_{ nullptr }, recv_cb_{ nullptr }, buffer_size_{ 4096 }
    {
    }

    TCPClient::~TCPClient()
    {
        Disconnect(); // be sure

        if (flags_ & flags::kTimerRunning)
        {
            connection_timer_.cancel();
            flags_ &= ~(flags::kTimerRunning);
        }
    }

    TConnectionPtr TCPClient::CreateSession()
    {
        return std::make_shared<TCPSession>(context_, buffer_size_);
    }

    void TCPClient::Connect(const std::string& host, std::uint16_t port)
    {
        if (connection_)
            connection_.reset();

        spdlog::debug("Starting connection to {}, {}", host, port);

        connection_ = CreateSession();
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(context_);
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(host, std::to_string(port)));

        boost::asio::async_connect(connection_->socket(), endpoints,
            [this, h = host, p = port](boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint)
            {
                if (!ec)
                {
                    flags_ &= ~(flags::kTimerRunning);

                    connection_->set_dc_cb([this]() {
                        connection_ = nullptr;
                    });


                    if (error_cb_)
                        connection_->set_error_cb(error_cb_);

                    if (recv_cb_)
                        connection_->set_recv_cb(recv_cb_);

                    if (connection_cb_)
                        connection_->set_connection_cb(connection_cb_);

                    connection_->OnConnection();
                    connection_->Read();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (connection_)
                        connection_->OnError(ec);

                    if (flags_ & flags::kReconnecting)
                    {
                        flags_ |= flags::kTimerRunning;
                        connection_timer_.expires_from_now(connection_timeout_);
                        connection_timer_.async_wait([this, h = h, p = p](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
                            if (!ec)
                            {
                                Connect(h, p);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                flags_ &= ~(flags::kTimerRunning);
                            }
                        }); 
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    void TCPClient::Disconnect()
    {
        if (!connection_)
            return;

        if (connection_->is_connected())
            connection_->Disconnect();

        connection_ = nullptr;
    }

    bool TCPClient::is_connected()
    {
        return connection_ ? connection_->is_connected() : false;
    }

    void TCPClient::set_connection_timeout(boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type connection_timeout)
    {
        connection_timeout_ = connection_timeout;
    }

    auto TCPClient::connection_timeout() -> boost::asio::deadline_timer::duration_type 
    { 
        return connection_timeout_;
    }

    TConnectionPtr& TCPClient::connection() 
    { 
        return connection_; 
    }

    void TCPClient::Send(void* pData, size_t length)
    {
        if (connection_)
            connection_->Send(pData, length);
    }

    void TCPClient::set_buffer_size(std::uint64_t buffer_size)
    {
        buffer_size_ = buffer_size_;
    }

    void TCPClient::set_reconnect(bool b)
    {
        if (b)
            flags_ |= flags::kReconnecting;
        else
            flags_ &= ~(flags::kReconnecting);
    }
}
```

TCPServer.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace nelw
{
    class option_wrapper
    {
        private:
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor_;
        public:
            option_wrapper(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& acceptor) : acceptor_(acceptor)
            {
            }
            ~option_wrapper() = default;

        template <typename SettableSocketOption>
        option_wrapper& set_option(const SettableSocketOption& option)
        {
            acceptor_.set_option(option);
            return *this;
        }
    };

    class TCPServer
    {
        public:
            using TConnectionMap = std::unordered_map<id_type, TConnectionPtr>;
        public:
            TCPServer(io_context_ref io_service);
            virtual ~TCPServer();
        public:
            void Run(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint&& e);
            void Run(std::uint16_t port, std::string_view ip = "127.0.0.1");
            void Stop();
        public:
            /**********************/
            /* getters & setters*/
            auto context()->io_context_ref { return context_; }
            auto acceptor()->tcp_acceptor& { return acceptor_; }

            template <typename SettableSocketOption>
            option_wrapper& set_option(const SettableSocketOption& option)
            {
                return option_wrapper_.set_option(option);
            }
            /**********************/
        protected:
            void Disconnect(std::shared_ptr<id_type> id);
            virtual void Accept();
            virtual TConnectionPtr CreateSession() // Override it
            {
                return std::make_shared<TCPSession>(context_, buffer_size_); 
            }
        public:
            template <class T> void set_connection_cb(T&& cb) { connection_cb_ = cb; }
            template <class T> void set_recv_cb(T&& cb) { recv_cb_ = cb; }
            template <class T> void set_error_cb(T&& cb) { error_cb_ = cb; }
            void set_buffer_size(std::uint64_t buffer_size); 
            void BroadCastPacket(void* pData, size_t length);
        protected:
            io_context_ref context_;
            tcp_acceptor acceptor_;
            id_type next_id_;
            TConnectionMap connection_map_;
            bool is_running_; 
            TConnectionCallback connection_cb_; 
            TErrorCallback error_cb_; 
            TRecvCallback recv_cb_; 
            std::uint64_t buffer_size_;
            option_wrapper option_wrapper_; 
    };
}
```

TCPServer.cpp

```cpp
#include "nelw/Base.hpp"
#include "nelw/TcpServer.hpp"
#include "nelw/TcpSession.hpp"
#include <algorithm>


namespace nelw
{
    TCPServer::TCPServer(io_context_ref io_service) : context_(io_service), acceptor_(context_), next_id_{ 0 }, is_running_(false), 
        connection_cb_{ nullptr }, error_cb_{ nullptr }, recv_cb_{ nullptr }, buffer_size_{ 4096 }, option_wrapper_(acceptor_)
    {
    }

    TCPServer::~TCPServer()
    {
        Stop();
    }

    void TCPServer::Run(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint&& e)
    {
        acceptor_.open(e.protocol());
        acceptor_.bind(e);
        acceptor_.listen();
        Accept();

        is_running_ = true;
    }

    void TCPServer::Run(std::uint16_t port, std::string_view ip)
    {
        Run(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address(ip), port));
    }

    void TCPServer::Disconnect(std::shared_ptr<id_type> id)
    {
        if (auto it = connection_map_.find(*id); it != connection_map_.end())
        {
            connection_map_.erase(it);
            spdlog::debug("Remove last id {0} left_size {1}", *id, connection_map_.size());
        }
    }

    void TCPServer::Stop()
    {
        if (!is_running_)
            return;

        if (!acceptor_.is_open())
            return;

        for (auto& [_, con] : connection_map_)
            con->Disconnect();

        acceptor_.cancel();
        acceptor_.close();

        is_running_ = false;
    }

    void TCPServer::Accept()
    {
        if (!acceptor_.is_open())
            return;

        auto session = CreateSession();
        acceptor_.async_accept(session->socket(), [this, session = session](boost::system::error_code const& ec) {
            if (!ec)
            {
                auto id = ++next_id_;
                session->set_id(id);
                connection_map_[id] = session;

                context_.post([this, idPtr = std::make_shared<id_type>(id), session = session, ec = ec]() {
                    if (error_cb_)
                        session->set_error_cb(error_cb_);

                    if (recv_cb_)
                        session->set_recv_cb(recv_cb_);

                    if (connection_cb_)
                        session->set_connection_cb(connection_cb_);

    
                    session->set_dc_cb(boost::bind(&TCPServer::Disconnect, this, idPtr));

                    session->Read();
                    Accept();
                    session->OnConnection();
                });

            }
            else
            {
                if (session)
                {
                    session->OnConnection();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void TCPServer::BroadCastPacket(void* pData, size_t length)
    {
        for (auto& [_, con] : connection_map_)
            if (con) con->Send(pData, length);
    }

    void TCPServer::set_buffer_size(std::uint64_t buffer_size)
    {
        buffer_size_ = buffer_size_;
    }
}
```

Buffer.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
// Modified from evpp project https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp
// @see https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp/blob/master/evpp/buffer.h and https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp/blob/master/evpp/buffer.cc
namespace nelw 
{
    class Buffer 
    {
    public:
        inline static constexpr size_t kCheapPrependSize = 8;
        inline static constexpr size_t kInitialSize = 1024;

        explicit Buffer(size_t initial_size = kInitialSize, size_t reserved_prepend_size = kCheapPrependSize)
            : capacity_(reserved_prepend_size + initial_size)
            , read_index_(reserved_prepend_size)
            , write_index_(reserved_prepend_size)
            , reserved_prepend_size_(reserved_prepend_size) {
            buffer_ = new char[capacity_];
            assert(length() == 0);
            assert(WritableBytes() == initial_size);
            assert(PrependableBytes() == reserved_prepend_size);
        }

        ~Buffer() {
            delete[] buffer_;
            buffer_ = nullptr;
            capacity_ = 0;
        }

        void Swap(Buffer& rhs) {
            std::swap(buffer_, rhs.buffer_);
            std::swap(capacity_, rhs.capacity_);
            std::swap(read_index_, rhs.read_index_);
            std::swap(write_index_, rhs.write_index_);
            std::swap(reserved_prepend_size_, rhs.reserved_prepend_size_);
        }

        // Skip advances the reading index of the buffer
        void Skip(size_t len) {
            if (len < length()) {
                read_index_ += len;
            }
            else {
                Reset();
            }
        }

        // Retrieve advances the reading index of the buffer
        // Retrieve it the same as Skip.
        void Retrieve(size_t len) {
            Skip(len);
        }

        // Truncate discards all but the first n unread bytes from the buffer
        // but continues to use the same allocated storage.
        // It does nothing if n is greater than the length of the buffer.
        void Truncate(size_t n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                read_index_ = reserved_prepend_size_;
                write_index_ = reserved_prepend_size_;
            }
            else if (write_index_ > read_index_ + n) {
                write_index_ = read_index_ + n;
            }
        }

        // Reset resets the buffer to be empty,
        // but it retains the underlying storage for use by future writes.
        // Reset is the same as Truncate(0).
        void Reset() {
            Truncate(0);
        }

        // Increase the capacity of the container to a value that's greater
        // or equal to len. If len is greater than the current capacity(),
        // new storage is allocated, otherwise the method does nothing.
        void Reserve(size_t len) {
            if (capacity_ >= len + reserved_prepend_size_) {
                return;
            }

            // TODO add the implementation logic here
            grow(len + reserved_prepend_size_);
        }

        // Make sure there is enough memory space to append more data with length len
        void EnsureWritableBytes(size_t len) {
            if (WritableBytes() < len) {
                grow(len);
            }

            assert(WritableBytes() >= len);
        }

        // ToText appends char '\0' to buffer to convert the underlying data to a c-style string text.
        // It will not change the length of buffer.
        void ToText() {
            AppendInt8('\0');
            UnwriteBytes(1);
        }

        // TODO XXX Little-Endian/Big-Endian problem.
#define evppbswap_64(x)                          \
    ((((x) & 0xff00000000000000ull) >> 56)       \
     | (((x) & 0x00ff000000000000ull) >> 40)     \
     | (((x) & 0x0000ff0000000000ull) >> 24)     \
     | (((x) & 0x000000ff00000000ull) >> 8)      \
     | (((x) & 0x00000000ff000000ull) << 8)      \
     | (((x) & 0x0000000000ff0000ull) << 24)     \
     | (((x) & 0x000000000000ff00ull) << 40)     \
     | (((x) & 0x00000000000000ffull) << 56))

    // Write
    public:
        void Write(const void* /*restrict*/ d, size_t len) {
            EnsureWritableBytes(len);
            memcpy(WriteBegin(), d, len);
            assert(write_index_ + len <= capacity_);
            write_index_ += len;
        }

        void Append(const char* /*restrict*/ d, size_t len) {
            Write(d, len);
        }

        void Append(const void* /*restrict*/ d, size_t len) {
            Write(d, len);
        }

        // Append int64_t/int32_t/int16_t with network endian
        void AppendInt64(int64_t x) {
            int64_t be = evppbswap_64(x);
            Write(&be, sizeof be);
        }

        void AppendInt32(int32_t x) {
            int32_t be32 = htonl(x);
            Write(&be32, sizeof be32);
        }

        void AppendInt16(int16_t x) {
            int16_t be16 = htons(x);
            Write(&be16, sizeof be16);
        }

        void AppendInt8(int8_t x) {
            Write(&x, sizeof x);
        }

        // Prepend int64_t/int32_t/int16_t with network endian
        void PrependInt64(int64_t x) {
            int64_t be = evppbswap_64(x);
            Prepend(&be, sizeof be);
        }

        void PrependInt32(int32_t x) {
            int32_t be32 = htonl(x);
            Prepend(&be32, sizeof be32);
        }

        void PrependInt16(int16_t x) {
            int16_t be16 = htons(x);
            Prepend(&be16, sizeof be16);
        }

        void PrependInt8(int8_t x) {
            Prepend(&x, sizeof x);
        }

        // Insert content, specified by the parameter, into the front of reading index
        void Prepend(const void* /*restrict*/ d, size_t len) {
            assert(len <= PrependableBytes());
            read_index_ -= len;
            const char* p = static_cast<const char*>(d);
            memcpy(begin() + read_index_, p, len);
        }

        void UnwriteBytes(size_t n) {
            assert(n <= length());
            write_index_ -= n;
        }

        void WriteBytes(size_t n) {
            assert(n <= WritableBytes());
            write_index_ += n;
        }

        //Read
    public:
        // Peek int64_t/int32_t/int16_t/int8_t with network endian
        int64_t ReadInt64() {
            int64_t result = PeekInt64();
            Skip(sizeof result);
            return result;
        }

        int32_t ReadInt32() {
            int32_t result = PeekInt32();
            Skip(sizeof result);
            return result;
        }

        int16_t ReadInt16() {
            int16_t result = PeekInt16();
            Skip(sizeof result);
            return result;
        }

        int8_t ReadInt8() {
            int8_t result = PeekInt8();
            Skip(sizeof result);
            return result;
        }

        std::string ToString() const {
            return std::string(data(), length());
        }

        void Shrink(size_t reserve) {
           // Buffer other(length() + reserve);
           // other.Append(ToSlice());
           // Swap(other);
        }

        // ReadByte reads and returns the next byte from the buffer.
        // If no byte is available, it returns '\0'.
        char ReadByte() {
            assert(length() >= 1);

            if (length() == 0) {
                return '\0';
            }

            return buffer_[read_index_++];
        }

        // UnreadBytes unreads the last n bytes returned
        // by the most recent read operation.
        void UnreadBytes(size_t n) {
            assert(n < read_index_);
            read_index_ -= n;
        }

        // Peek
    public:
        // Peek int64_t/int32_t/int16_t/int8_t with network endian
        int64_t PeekInt64() const {
            assert(length() >= sizeof(int64_t));
            int64_t be64 = 0;
            ::memcpy(&be64, data(), sizeof be64);
            return evppbswap_64(be64);
        }

        int32_t PeekInt32() const {
            assert(length() >= sizeof(int32_t));
            int32_t be32 = 0;
            ::memcpy(&be32, data(), sizeof be32);
            return ntohl(be32);
        }

        int16_t PeekInt16() const {
            assert(length() >= sizeof(int16_t));
            int16_t be16 = 0;
            ::memcpy(&be16, data(), sizeof be16);
            return ntohs(be16);
        }

        int8_t PeekInt8() const {
            assert(length() >= sizeof(int8_t));
            int8_t x = *data();
            return x;
        }

    public:
        // data returns a pointer of length Buffer.length() holding the unread portion of the buffer.
        // The data is valid for use only until the next buffer modification (that is,
        // only until the next call to a method like Read, Write, Reset, or Truncate).
        // The data aliases the buffer content at least until the next buffer modification,
        // so immediate changes to the slice will affect the result of future reads.
        const char* data() const {
            return buffer_ + read_index_;
        }

        char* WriteBegin() {
            return begin() + write_index_;
        }

        const char* WriteBegin() const {
            return begin() + write_index_;
        }

        // length returns the number of bytes of the unread portion of the buffer
        size_t length() const {
            assert(write_index_ >= read_index_);
            return write_index_ - read_index_;
        }

        // size returns the number of bytes of the unread portion of the buffer.
        // It is the same as length().
        size_t size() const {
            return length();
        }

        // capacity returns the capacity of the buffer's underlying byte slice, that is, the
        // total space allocated for the buffer's data.
        size_t capacity() const {
            return capacity_;
        }

        size_t WritableBytes() const {
            assert(capacity_ >= write_index_);
            return capacity_ - write_index_;
        }

        size_t PrependableBytes() const {
            return read_index_;
        }

        // Helpers
    public:
        const char* FindCRLF() const {
            const char* crlf = std::search(data(), WriteBegin(), kCRLF, kCRLF + 2);
            return crlf == WriteBegin() ? nullptr : crlf;
        }

        const char* FindCRLF(const char* start) const {
            assert(data() <= start);
            assert(start <= WriteBegin());
            const char* crlf = std::search(start, WriteBegin(), kCRLF, kCRLF + 2);
            return crlf == WriteBegin() ? nullptr : crlf;
        }

        const char* FindEOL() const {
            const void* eol = memchr(data(), '\n', length());
            return static_cast<const char*>(eol);
        }

        const char* FindEOL(const char* start) const {
            assert(data() <= start);
            assert(start <= WriteBegin());
            const void* eol = memchr(start, '\n', WriteBegin() - start);
            return static_cast<const char*>(eol);
        }
    private:

        char* begin() {
            return buffer_;
        }

        const char* begin() const {
            return buffer_;
        }

        void grow(size_t len) {
            if (WritableBytes() + PrependableBytes() < len + reserved_prepend_size_) {
                //grow the capacity
                size_t n = (capacity_ << 1) + len;
                size_t m = length();
                char* d = new char[n];
                memcpy(d + reserved_prepend_size_, begin() + read_index_, m);
                write_index_ = m + reserved_prepend_size_;
                read_index_ = reserved_prepend_size_;
                capacity_ = n;
                delete[] buffer_;
                buffer_ = d;
            }
            else {
                // move readable data to the front, make space inside buffer
                assert(reserved_prepend_size_ < read_index_);
                size_t readable = length();
                memmove(begin() + reserved_prepend_size_, begin() + read_index_, length());
                read_index_ = reserved_prepend_size_;
                write_index_ = read_index_ + readable;
                assert(readable == length());
                assert(WritableBytes() >= len);
            }
        }

    private:
        char* buffer_;
        size_t capacity_;
        size_t read_index_;
        size_t write_index_;
        size_t reserved_prepend_size_;
        inline static constexpr const char kCRLF[3] = { "\r\n" };
    };
}
```

Echo Server example:

```cpp
#include <nelw/nelw.hpp>
auto main() -> int
{
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%l][%t] %v");
    boost::asio::io_context context; 
    std::uint16_t port = 9005; 
    auto srv = std::make_unique<nelw::TCPServer>(context);
    srv->Run(port);
    srv->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true)).
         set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay(true));
    srv->set_recv_cb([](const nelw::TConnectionPtr& con, const nelw::TBufferPtr& buf) {
        if (auto size = buf->length(); size)
        {
            auto str = buf->ToString();
            con->Send((void*)str.data(), str.size());
            buf->Skip(size);
        }
    });

    context.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Base.hpp` drags in a lot of stuff that isn't needed for what it defines:

> ```
> #define SPDLOG_ACTIVE_LEVEL 1
> #include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
> #include <spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h>
> #include <spdlog/async.h>
> #include "Utils.hpp"
> ```

As far as I can see, all of these can be removed, and only included by the implementation files that need them.